# how to get NOT crashed image file from Unity to Django?

Tags: django, http, unity-game-engine, post, request

I'm using Unity 2018.3. and try to HTTP POST Request with image from Unity to Django.

try to take a picture in Unity and then POST the image to Django server. 
I want to receive in server and make it to image file.


well, when i send for image file to byte[] using EncodeToPNG() or EncodeToJPG(), the server got it but when i print it the data it was crash seems like encoding error. so it can't write to image format. (the take a picture code is working right.)
[Django server result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R06Bv.png)

i saw a bunch of things about this issue so i tried to other way like use WWWform or JSON but anything couldn't works..

how to get image form Unity to Django?
All help appreciated! Thanks, all.

**take a picture**

```
 void TakeSnapshot()
 {
     Texture2D snap = new Texture2D(frontCam.width, frontCam.height);
     snap.SetPixels(frontCam.GetPixels());
     snap.Apply();

     _SavePath = pathForDocumentsFile("photo");
     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_SavePath + ".png", snap.EncodeToPNG());

     bytes = snap.EncodeToPNG();
     //bytes = snap.EncodeToJPG();

     UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(snap);

     path = _SavePath + ".png";

     StartCoroutine(ServerThrows());
 }
```

**POST to server**

```
 IEnumerator ServerThrows()
 {
     List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
     formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("photo", bytes, "byte[]"));

     //UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, null, bytes);
     UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);
     www.chunkedTransfer = false;
     yield return www.SendWebRequest();

     if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
     {
         Debug.Log(www.error);
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("Form upload complete!" + www.downloadHandler.text);
     }
 }
```

**response in server**

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
     print('get the data')

     print('request.POST: ', request.POST)
     print('request.headers: ', request.headers)

     data_test = request.POST.get('photo', '')

     print('data test is : ', data_test)
     print('type of data_test is : ', type(data_test))
     print('length of data_test is : ', len(data_test))
     print('finish to get ')
     # data_test = data_test.decode('utf-8').encode('euc_kr','replace')

     f = open('./test.png','wb')
     f.write(data_test.encode())
     f.close()

     #
     data = open('./test.png', 'rb')

     return HttpResponse("post !")
```

Comment: Part of me would suggest you dont need to "encodetopng" when downloading it, but just save the bytes as they came in as you sent a png.

Comment: 1. `snap.EncodeToPNG` is very performance instense and you should use it only once and rather flip some lines like `path = _SavePath + ".png"; bytes = snap.EncodeToPNG; System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);` 2. The `contentType` parameter of `MultipartFormDataSection` should not be `byte[]` but rather a correct [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) I guess something like e.g. `image/png`

Comment: [SOLVED] i'm just using `UnityWebRequest`